# How to customise Oh My ZSH within a Spacemacs shell?

Tags: emacs, zsh, oh-my-zsh, ansi-escape, spacemacs

## Context

I have a nice and beautiful setup on **iTerm2** (I'm using a Mac) where the default shell is **ZSH** and it is properly customized using **Oh-my-zsh** and the **Agnoster-fcamblor** Theme.

[image]

---

## Issue

As a Spacemacs user, I would like to do as much as possible without leaving Emacs. So I decided to invoke a *terminal* window from inside of it, as I'm used to doing with Vim/tmux.

This is the look that I get (in the same directory):

[image]

---

## Things I've checked

Apparently the Theme is not being applied.

This is the relevant part of my `~/.spacemacs`:

```
(shell :variables
        shell-default-shell 'ansi-term
        shell-default-height 30
        shell-default-term-shell "/bin/zsh"
        shell-default-position 'bottom)
```

**A few important things:**

- **`$> echo $0`** shows me **ZSH** is the shell being used inside Spacemacs.
- **`$> echo $PS1`** shows me it is properly set and it matches *iTerm2*.
- I tried sourcing the configuration file I use but, as the above fact suggests, it is already being loaded.

---

## Question

How can I apply the Oh-my-zsh Theme inside a Spacemacs Shell Window?

Comment: @jaysoifer actually, my problems comes from the M-x shell command. I didn't try since a while so maybe I changed something relevant in my config but now, it is working well just with M-x ansi-term

Answer (score 3):

Instead of trying to make **Spacemacs** options override the terminal options (wasn't able to do it), I decided to match the Spacemacs Theme with the *Agnoster-Fcamblor* theme I've been using, this way both have the same colors and backgrounds (a.k.a. skin/theme).

**1. Inside *dotspacemacs-additional-packages*:**

```lisp
color-theme-solarized
```

**2. Inside *dotspacemacs/user-config*:**

(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()

```
;; Fix separators
(setq ns-use-srgb-colorspace nil)
;; (setq powerline-default-separator 'utf-8)
;; Theme Customizations
(setq theming-modifications
    '((solarized
       ;; Provide a sort of "on-off" modeline whereby the current buffer has a nice
       ;; bright blue background, and all the others are in cream.
       ;; TODO: Change to use variables here. However, got error:
       ;; (Spacemacs) Error in dotspacemacs/user-config: Wrong type argument: stringp, pd-blue
       (mode-line :foreground "#e9e2cb" :background "#2075c7" :inverse-video nil)
       (powerline-active1 :foreground "#e9e2cb" :background "#2075c7" :inverse-video nil)
       (powerline-active2 :foreground "#e9e2cb" :background "#2075c7" :inverse-video nil)
       (mode-line-inactive :foreground "#2075c7" :background "#e9e2cb" :inverse-video nil)
       (powerline-inactive1 :foreground "#2075c7" :background "#e9e2cb" :inverse-video nil)
       (powerline-inactive2 :foreground "#2075c7" :background "#e9e2cb" :inverse-video nil)
       ;; Make a really prominent helm selection line.
       (helm-selection :foreground "white" :background "#2075c7" :inverse-video nil)
       ;; See comment above about dotspacemacs-colorize-cursor-according-to-state.
       (cursor :background "#b58900")
     )))
```